# How to recover from drive failure on lvm software raid 10 in Linux?

Tags: lvm, software-raid, raid10

Below is how I created lvm software raid10.

Create Physical Volumes
`pvcreate /dev/nvme0n1 /dev/nvme1n1 /dev/nvme2n1 /dev/nvme3n1`

Create Volume Group
`vgcreate my_vol_grp /dev/nvme0n1 /dev/nvme1n1 /dev/nvme2n1 /dev/nvme3n1`

Create a logical volume with RAID10 from the already created volume group
`lvcreate --type raid10 -m 1 -i 2 -l 100%FREE -n lvm_raid10 my_vol_grp`

Create ext4 filesystem on the logical volume that you have created
`mkfs.ext4 /dev/my_vol_grp/lvm_raid10`

Now the question is, how do I recover and re-establish raid10 after 1 drive failure on lvm raid10 configuration. I can find a lot of information online about how to create lvm raid10. However, I can not find much information about how to recover in case the drive fails.

Also my server supports hot-swap. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the new disk to the VG. Your VG and disk names will vary.

```
vgextend vg /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-0QEMU_QEMU_HARDDISK_drive-scsi-disk-1
```

Based on [the lvmraid manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man7/lvmraid.7.html), regarding Replacing Devices, unavailable PVs call for a repair operation.

```
lvconvert --repair vg/lv
```

Comment: Ty for the answer. Just checked the documentation. Clarifies the process.